# Showing separate title for different site when using Managed Metadata for Global Navigation (screenshots)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, navigation, managed-metadata, term-store

I am using Managed MetaData Service to display Global Navigation on my site.

If you take a look at the following screenshot you will see I have created two labels for both English and Arabic.

For English it is called Home
For Arabic it is called منزل(it is not visible in screenshot but it is there)

[image: Screenshot1]

I thought now SharePoint will automatically show appropriate label based on site select but that's not the case. It is showing "Home" for both English and Arabic sites.

And it is because SharePoint is showing label from "Navigation Node Title" as shown in following screenshot. As you can see there is no option to define another title for Arabic language.

Does it mean I will have to create a separate Term Set in Managed Metadata for Arabic site and then use it in Global Navigation?

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: you could try this! its exactly what your trying to do! http://parallelmindsblog.com/tag/variations-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Sorry this is not what I am asking. I have already created variations and my question is about top navigation.

Answer (score 0):

With Variations the Navigation works properly if you create your Target Variation Label with the right Language Pack for the Template:
[image: Spanish Language Pack for Template]
AND than you have to visit your page with the correct Language Settings in your internet browser:
[image: Spanish Language Settings in Firefox]